# JGraphT: How to use JSONImporter to Import my DirectedMultigraph with Labeled Edges

Tags: java-8, jgrapht

I have created a custom edge class [as defined here](https://jgrapht.org/guide/LabeledEdges). The only change I made was a `No Arg` constructor in order to get the import code below to run. I have successfully generated a `DirectedMultigraph` via the [JSONExporter](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-SNAPSHOT/org/jgrapht/io/JSONExporter.html) class and now want to take that exported JSON and re-import it via the [JSONImporter](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-SNAPSHOT/org/jgrapht/io/JSONImporter.html) class.

I'm having trouble doing this and retaining my edge labels due to my limited understanding of how to build the `EdgeProvider` required for my `JSONImporter` constructor.

This is the JSON I'm trying to import:

```
{
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "{shipmentNumber:12345}",
      "source": "DEHAM",
      "target": "USNYC"
    }
  ],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "DEHAM"
    },
    {
      "id": "USNYC"
    }
  ],
  "creator": "JGraphT JSON Exporter",
  "version": "1"
}
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
Graph<String, RelationshipEdge> graph = new DirectedMultigraph<>(SupplierUtil.createStringSupplier(), SupplierUtil.createSupplier(RelationshipEdge.class), false);

VertexProvider<String> vertexProvider = (label, attributes) -> label;

EdgeProvider<String, RelationshipEdge> edgeProvider =
              (from, to, label, attributes) -> graph.getEdgeSupplier().get();

JSONImporter<String, RelationshipEdge> importer = new JSONImporter<>(vertexProvider, edgeProvider);

importer.importGraph(graph, new StringReader([inputJSON]);
```

I know the problem is the `EdgeProvider` assignment because I don't know how to pass the argument constructor for the RelationshipEdge class which is where the actual label is set. If I could figure out how to call the argument constructor of the RelationshipEdge class then I think that would solve my problem.

FYI, this is my JSONExporter Code:

```
ComponentNameProvider<String> vertexIdProvider = name -> name;
ComponentNameProvider<RelationshipEdge> edgeLabelProvider = component -> component.getLabel();
ComponentAttributeProvider<String> vertexAttributeProvider = component -> new HashMap<>();
ComponentAttributeProvider<RelationshipEdge> edgeAttributeProvider = component -> new HashMap<>();


GraphExporter<String, RelationshipEdge> jsonExporter = new JSONExporter<>(vertexIdProvider, vertexAttributeProvider, edgeLabelProvider, edgeAttributeProvider);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
jsonExporter.exportGraph(graph, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

The following JSON is exported (with the label/id missing):

```
{
  "creator": "JGraphT JSON Exporter",
  "version": "1",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "DEHAM"
    },
    {
      "id": "USNYC"
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "source": "DEHAM",
      "target": "USNYC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your graph is using the SupplierUtil factory methods, the graph importer will use no-arg constructors as it visits/parses the json file, iterates over all the nodes/edges in the file and creates instances for them. In order to set your node/edge attributes during import you need to provide appropriate Vertex/Edge Attribute Consumers to the importer. Additionally, your node/edge classes need methods to access/modify their attributes:

```
JSONImporter<String, RelationshipEdge> importer = new JSONImporter<>(vertexProvider, edgeProvider);
importer.addEdgeAttributeConsumer((edgeField, value) -> {
  // edgeField: Pair<Edge, String> / Edge instance, field name
  // value: instance of org.jgrapht.nio.Attribute / getValue(); getType();
  RelationshipEdge = edgeField.getFirst();
  e.setLabel(value.getValue());  // Note that since you only have one field I am not finding the
                                 // correct setter. I don't like reflection so I would probably
                                 // add a 'setField(name, value)' method to my edge/node implementation.
    });
```

To persist your graph, the idea is the same. But in this case you need Vertex/Edge AttributeProviders (You added them but they always returned empty maps):

```
GraphExporter<String, RelationshipEdge> jsonExporter = new JSONExporter<>();
exporter.setEdgeAttributeProvider(e -> {
            Map<String, Attribute> attribs = new HashMap<>();
            attribs.put("label", new DefaultAttribute<String>(e.getLabel(), AttributeType.STRING));
            return attribs;
        });
```